# How to put month and year in database according to end of year

Tags: php, mysql

i have some checkboxes which created by For loop like this:

```
for ($i=1; $i <= $loan['loanreqmonth']; $i++)
{
    echo '<input name="loan['.$i.']" type="checkbox" value="'.$i.'">loan # '.$i.'</div>';
}
```

and i process and import the selected checkboxes whith something like this:

```
foreach($_POST['loan'] as $loan)
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `loanpays`(`loanid`,`type`,`num`,`codemelli`, `price`, `month`, `year`,`stamp`) VALUES ('$loan[ID]','loan','$loan','$_SESSION[codemelli]','$priceloan','$month','$year','$stamp')");
}
```

i want to put month (1-12) and year(2017-2020) from current month and year for each selected checkbox.
for example the first checkbox month is (11) and year is(2017)
the next one is 12 / 2017
but the problem is the next one is 1 / 2018!

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated as of [tag:php-5.5]. So instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection). Use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: what is the content of the $loan['loanreqmonth']?

Comment: $loan['loanreqmonth'] is the number of pays that user must pay.

Comment: The problem inor clear from the question

Comment: @AliKhedmati it is unclear how the month and year are generated

Comment: $date=date('d'); And $year=date('Y');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly:

Look at modulo operator (`%`) it gives you a remainer after division by the specified number - lets say `2 % 12 = 2`, `13 % 12 = 1` - this will allow you to loop through months 1 to 12 infinitely, you just need to take care of the 12 month because 12 % 12 will give you 0 where you need 12.

Too iterate the year, simply check whether the current loop month value is divisable by 12 (`x % 12 == 0`) and if so iterate the year at the end of loop, cause next month will be January of next year...

Comment: thanks for your useful guide! i have $loanmonth=18; and it is the number of payments which user must pay for this loan.i want the first loan date to be current month and year(eg. 2017/11) till 18 months ( in this case 2019/4),is it possible?

Comment: then just dont start the loop from 1 (`for($i=1;...`), but from 11 (`for($i=11;...`)

Comment: i wrote this and its successfully works for returning months but how can i write something for years?

Comment: for ($i=1; $i <= $loanreqmonth; $i++){

if($i%12 == 0){
 $b=12;
 }
elseif($i%12 != 0){
 $b=$i%12;
 }
     echo'<input name="loan['.$i.']" type="checkbox" value="'.$b.'">loan #   '.$b.'</label>
</div>
';}

Comment: as you can see i use if clause for the month 12 and i dont know how to iterate year !

Comment: before the loop, declare a variable and give it value of the starting year:`$year = <starting_year>`, then add a condition to the last line of the loop to iterate the year if you reached last month of the year `if($i % 12 == 0){$year++}`

Comment: i did it but for the month no 12 of every year;the `{$year++}` runs!

Comment: So everything is working as it should be now? If so, I was glad to help!

Comment: there is a problem! for example the first checkbox month is 10 and  year is 2017 , next one is 11/2017 and the next is 12/2018 ! i have problem with month 12 of every year.here is the code: `for ($i=1; $i <= $loanreqmonth; $i++){

if($i%12 == 0){
 $b=12;
 }
elseif($i%12 != 0){
 $b=$i%12;
 }
 if($i%12 == 0){$years++;}}`

Comment: you need to put the `if($i%12 == 0){$years++;}` after your `echo<input...` code

Comment: Thank you very much! You completely solved my problem,Thanks a lot buddy ♥